# How to get null values in left join and avoid duplicate entry in mysql?

Tags: mysql, left-join

Left join brings already entered duplicate values for null in left join mysql

This is for Bed Management System -  wardwise bed status

I have got two tables to join to get data on the no of beds based on its status and the ward it belongs to, below is mu query

```
    SELECT a.bedno 'Bed Number', 
       a.bedtype 'Bed Type', 
       b.hno 'Patient ID', 
       b.NAME 'Patient Name', 
       c.unitsectionname'Unit Name', 
       b.sex 'Sex', 
       a.includestat 'Bed status' 
FROM   bedmaster a 
       LEFT JOIN admissionmaster b 
              ON a.bedno = b.bedno 
       LEFT JOIN unitsectionmaster c 
              ON b.unitcode = c.unitsectioncode 
WHERE  a.f_wardcode = 'W001';
```

Data:

```
+-------+---------+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+
| bedno | bedtype | includestat | name      | hno     | unitsectionname |
+-------+---------+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+
| 101   | sbc     | O           | asdsadasd | 000061C | General surgery |
| 201   | dba     | A           | nisar     | 000045c | General surgery |
| 301   | sbc     | A           | NULL      | NULL    | NULL            |
| 401   | db      | A           | NULL      | NULL    | NULL            |
| 102   | sb      | O           | Rudolf    | 000167C | General surgery |
| 103   | sba     | A           | NULL      | NULL    | NULL            |
| 302   | dba     | A           | NULL      | NULL    | NULL            |
| 402   | sb      | A           | NULL      | NULL    | NULL            |
| 104   | sbc     | A           | NULL      | NULL    | NULL            |
| 105   | sb      | A           | NULL      | NULL    | NULL            |
+-------+---------+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+
```

My query allows duplicate entry for bed no 201 inspite of its status is available. When bed is available it should be null,but it brings the records of the patient admitted already.

Admission Master - table 1

```
+-----------+------+-------+---------+
| name      | sex  | bedno | bedtype |
+-----------+------+-------+---------+
| asdsadasd | F    | 101   | sbc     |
| nisar     | F    | 201   | dba     |
| Rudolf    | F    | 102   | sb      |
| Modi      | F    | 001z  | qwe     |
+-----------+------+-------+---------+
```

Bedmaster- table 2

```
+----------+-------+---------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----+--------------+---------+-------------+--+
| wardcode | bedno | bedtype | createdon  | createdby | modifiedon | modifiedby | unitcode | bedstatus | createdip | modifiedip | icu | recordactive | allowed | includestat |  |
+----------+-------+---------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----+--------------+---------+-------------+--+
| W001     |   101 | sbc     | 2015-10-14 | P         | NULL       | NULL       |      203 | Y         | ::1       | NULL       | y   | Y            | A       | O           |  |
+----------+-------+---------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----+--------------+---------+-------------+--+
```

Comment: Show sample data of the tables?

Comment: Admission Master:                                   +-----------+------+-------+---------+
| name      | sex  | bedno | bedtype |
+-----------+------+-------+---------+
| asdsadasd | F    | 101   | sbc     |    
| nisar     | F    | 201   | dba     |
| Rudolf    | F    | 102   | sb      |
| Modi      | F    | 001z  | qwe     |
+-----------+------+-------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: also show sample data of other two tables

Comment: Please add sample data to the question and not in comment..

Comment: I've added sample data..please check out !

Comment: Do Bedmaster- table has multiple entries for bedno?

Comment: Yeah it has multiple entries !